# Why does advancing/retreating the month remove all events from the calendar in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript

http://bit.ly/1jrzpIx

1. Visit the link noted above.  See the calendar.  See the calendar events.
2. Now advance to the next month using the arrow buttons near the top left.
3. Now go back to the current month.  Observe that the calendar events have disappeared. This is not expected behaviour.
4. Now change the view so that you are in week or day mode.
5. Now return to the month mode and observe that the events have re-appeared on the current month.

Objective: Fix this calendar so that it retains its current functionality but does not lose the events when the months are paged through.

More information: This is Drupal v. 7.26.  (latest)

And you can find the Drupal FullCalendar module here: https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar

And here is a bug report that I think deals with this issue, at least they seem to be related. My post is near the bottom of this thread. I've turned off AJAX so I don't think that's the problem.

https://drupal.org/node/1864992

Here is an answer on StackOverflow on (maybe) how to fix it. I don't know how to run the eventsRender method after fullCalendar instantiates in Drupal.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665469/fullcalendar-cannot-display-the-new-event-when-switch-month-back

Here is another one (maybe):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195156/when-switching-months-i-want-to-stop-fullcalendar-from-removing-events

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your calendar now it looks like you have it fixed.  I was gonna' offer the solution that I was told:  Make your site's short date format to use "2014-5-19 17:30"  Unfortunately it had to be in military time, not 12 hour or it didn't work.  That is only an issue when looking at the "upcoming events" that I have listed at the bottom of my calendar in another block.  I was going to go the ajax method if I can get 12 hour time to work with ajax, using the fix offered for Ajax at the drupal posts on this issue; haven't tried it yet.

So what solution did you get to work for you?

Dave N

Comment: I don't think the problem I was having was related to date format, but then again, it's possible I overlooked something. In the end I created a custom view template that renders the events using php. It's not elegant or foolproof but works most of the time.

Comment: I applied the patch to the javascript and it took care of my problem.  Works great now.